# Unable to run JAR - Spark Twitter Streaming with Java

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter4j

I'm running Spark 2.4.3 in standalone mode in Ubuntu. I am using Maven to create the JAR file. Below is the code I'm trying to run which is intended to stream data from Twitter.
Once Spark is started Spark master will be at 127.0.1.1:7077.
The java version being used is 1.8.

```
package SparkTwitter.SparkJavaTwitter;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils;

import scala.Tuple2;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.auth.Authorization;
import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;


public class TwitterStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prepare the spark configuration by setting application name and master node "local" i.e. embedded mode
        final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Twitter Data Processing").setMaster("local[2]");
        // Create Streaming context using spark configuration and duration for which messages will be batched and fed to Spark Core
        final JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Duration.apply(10000));

        // Prepare configuration for Twitter authentication and authorization
        final Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder().setDebugEnabled(false)
                                        .setOAuthConsumerKey("customer key")
                                        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("customer key secret")
                                        .setOAuthAccessToken("Access token")
                                        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("Access token secret")
                                        .build();
        // Create Twitter authorization object by passing prepared configuration containing consumer and access keys and tokens
        final Authorization twitterAuth = new OAuthAuthorization(conf);
        // Create a data stream using streaming context and Twitter authorization
        final JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> inputDStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(streamingContext, twitterAuth, new String[]{});
        // Create a new stream by filtering the non english tweets from earlier streams
        final JavaDStream<Status> enTweetsDStream = inputDStream.filter((status) -> "en".equalsIgnoreCase(status.getLang()));
        // Convert stream to pair stream with key as user screen name and value as tweet text
        final JavaPairDStream<String, String> userTweetsStream = 
                                enTweetsDStream.mapToPair(
                                    (status) -> new Tuple2<String, String>(status.getUser().getScreenName(), status.getText())
                                );

        // Group the tweets for each user
        final JavaPairDStream<String, Iterable<String>> tweetsReducedByUser = userTweetsStream.groupByKey();
        // Create a new pair stream by replacing iterable of tweets in older pair stream to number of tweets
        final JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> tweetsMappedByUser = tweetsReducedByUser.mapToPair(
                    userTweets -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(userTweets._1, Iterables.size(userTweets._2))
                );
        // Iterate over the stream's RDDs and print each element on console
        tweetsMappedByUser.foreachRDD((VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>>)pairRDD -> {
            pairRDD.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public void call(Tuple2<String, Integer> t) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(t._1() + "," + t._2());
                }

            });
        });
        // Triggers the start of processing. Nothing happens if streaming context is not started
        streamingContext.start();
        // Keeps the processing live by halting here unless terminated manually
        //streamingContext.awaitTermination();

    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>SparkTwitter</groupId>
  <artifactId>SparkJavaTwitter</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SparkJavaTwitter</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

To execute the code I'm using the following command

```
./bin/spark-submit --class SparkTwitter.SparkJavaTwitter.TwitterStream /home/hadoop/eclipse-workspace/SparkJavaTwitter/target/SparkJavaTwitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Below is the output I'm getting.

```
19/11/10 22:17:58 WARN Utils: Your hostname, hadoop-VirtualBox resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
19/11/10 22:17:58 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
19/11/10 22:17:58 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Warning: Failed to load SparkTwitter.SparkJavaTwitter.TwitterStream: twitter4j/auth/Authorization
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I've been running a word count program the same way and it works fine. When I build the JAR it builds successfully as well. Do I have to specify any more parameters while running the JAR?

Comment: is it a fat jar ?

Comment: @voldy sorry I'm not sure. I build the JAR in Maven as follows. Right click on the project then Run As -> Maven build... When I run the code in Eclipse it works. However once I try to run the jar in the command line it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem and found that you need to give the jars directly to spark-submit. What I do is point out the directory where the jars used to build the project are stored using the `--jars "<path-to-jars>/*"` option to spark-submit.

Perhaps this is not the best option, but it works...

Also, when updating versions beware that the jars in that folder must also be updated.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. The jars for this project are added using a pom.xml. They aren't stored locally. However as the problem is with one particular class twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder I tried downloading the same jar from Maven and specifying the path in --jars and --packages parameters and re-running it. But it didn't work. Can we add a URL for the jars path?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that before running, the spark system will download the jars required and then use them locally. You can even consult the cache folder (typically `~/.ivy2`). So in fact the pom is a set of indirect URLs. Are you sure you have the correct version of Twitter4J?

Comment: you were right. I found the location of the jars. My bad. I tried specifying only the twitter4j jar woth --packages but didn't work. I'll check the jar versions again. However the program runs fine when I run it in Eclipse as a Java application. The problem is only when running the program after converting it to a jar.

Comment: For some reason, spark does not recognise the jars inside the jar you submit. I believe the standard solution is providing extra jars as mentioned above. Or perhaps there is some option for that that I'm not aware of.